# Table border does not automatically fit into contents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I have an invoice being constructed via iTextSharp (4.1.2).

My problem lies on a certain part of my invoice wherein I display the terms and conditions and the payment terms. The following image below shows my problem.

[image: Output from the code provided below.]

However, when the dynamic rows are not present (I mean no selected discounts, no shipping costs and no tax, just subtotal and grand total), the appearance is similar to the image. My bottom border falls down to the far bottom instead of within the cell.

**Constraints**:

- Upgrading is not yet an option for now as there are already printing
  functionalities that require iTextSharp 4.1.2.
- Using HTML to PDF is not yet an option also because of time constraints.

I hope you can help me with this.

**EDIT**: Revised the question to reflect output and code for replication.

```js
    protected void btnViewPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create a document in memory with default settings.
        var document = new Document();
        string path = Server.MapPath("PDFs");

        // Commit the document to disk.
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(path + "/PaymentDetails.pdf", FileMode.Create));

        // Open th document.
        document.Open();
        
        #region Do your PDF document logic here...

        // Create a PdfPTable to contain two columns. This will be used for the layout.
        PdfPTable outerTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        outerTable.TotalWidth = 510f;
        outerTable.LockedWidth = true;
        outerTable.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;

        #region First Column

        // Add PdfPTable in the first column.
        PdfPTable outerTableFirstColumn = new PdfPTable(1);
        outerTableFirstColumn.TotalWidth = 450f;
        outerTableFirstColumn.DefaultCell.BorderColor = Color.BLACK;

        // Add cells to the first column.
        PdfPCell outerTableFirstColumnHeader = new PdfPCell()
            {
                Border = Rectangle.BOX,
                BorderColor = Color.BLACK,
                Phrase = new Phrase("Terms and Conditions", FontFactory.GetFont("Consolas", 8, (int) Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)),
                Padding = 5f
            };

        outerTableFirstColumn.AddCell(outerTableFirstColumnHeader);

        String myTermsAndConditions = "Acceptance and Cancellation of Orders. An invoice accepted by the Customer may not be cancelled by the Customer and constitutes a binding agreement between the Customer and the Company. In the event of cancellation or other withdrawal of an order by Customer for any reason and without limiting any other remedy which the Company may have as a result of such cancellation or other withdrawal, reasonable cancellation charges, which shall include all expenses then incurred and commitments made by the Company, shall be paid by the Customer to the Company.";
        
        PdfPCell outerTableFirstColumnContent = new PdfPCell()
        {
            Border = Rectangle.BOX,
            BorderColor = Color.BLACK,
            Phrase = new Phrase(myTermsAndConditions, FontFactory.GetFont("Consolas", 8, (int)Font.NORMAL, Color.BLACK)),
            Padding = 5f
        };

        outerTableFirstColumn.AddCell(outerTableFirstColumnContent);

        #endregion

        #region Second Column

        // Add PdfPTable in the second column.
        PdfPTable outerTableSecondColumn = new PdfPTable(1);
        outerTableSecondColumn.TotalWidth = 70f;
        outerTableSecondColumn.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;
        
        PdfPTable outerTableSecondColumnContent = new PdfPTable(3);
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.SetWidths(new float[] { 3f, 0.5f, 1.5f });
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOX;

        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Subtotal:"));
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("999.99"));

        #region Conditional adding of cells

        // Initialize details which can be controlled to produce results.
        var subTotal = 999.99M;

        var selectedDiscountType = DiscountType.NoDiscount;
        var flatDiscountAmount = 30M;
        var discountRate = 23.18M;
        var discountPercentAmount = 0.00M;

        var selectedTaxType = TaxType.NoTax;
        var flatTaxAmount = 20.00M;
        var taxRate = 12.25M;
        var taxPercentAmount = 0.00M;

        var includeShipping = false;
        var shippingCost = 20.50M;

        if (selectedDiscountType != 0)
        {
            switch (selectedDiscountType)
            {
                case DiscountType.FlatDiscount:
                    {
                        // Discount Amount
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Flat Discount:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(decimal.Parse(flatDiscountAmount.ToString()).ToString("N")));
                    }
                    break;
                case DiscountType.PercentDiscount:
                    {
                        flatDiscountAmount = 0;

                        // Discount Rate
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("% Discount:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(" "));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(String.Format(discountRate.ToString(), "{0:0.0}")));

                        discountPercentAmount = subTotal * (discountRate / 100);

                        // Total Discount
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Total Discount:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(decimal.Parse(discountPercentAmount.ToString()).ToString("N")));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (includeShipping)
        {
            // Shipping Cost
            outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Shipping Cost:"));
            outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
            outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(decimal.Parse(shippingCost.ToString()).ToString("N")));
        }

        if (selectedTaxType != 0)
        {
            switch (selectedTaxType)
            {
                case TaxType.FlatTax:
                    {
                        // Tax Amount
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Flat Tax:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(decimal.Parse(flatTaxAmount.ToString()).ToString("N")));
                    }
                    break;
                case TaxType.PercentTax:
                    {
                        flatTaxAmount = 0;

                        // Tax Percent
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("% Tax:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(" "));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(String.Format(taxRate.ToString(), "{0:0.0}")));

                        taxPercentAmount = (subTotal - (flatDiscountAmount + discountPercentAmount) + (shippingCost)) * (taxRate / 100);

                        // Total Tax
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Total Tax:"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
                        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell(decimal.Parse(taxPercentAmount.ToString()).ToString("N")));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        var grandTotalCost = (subTotal - (flatDiscountAmount + discountPercentAmount) + shippingCost) + (flatTaxAmount + taxPercentAmount);

        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("Grand Total:"));
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GeneratePaymentDetailCell("$"));
        outerTableSecondColumnContent.AddCell(GenerateGrandTotalCostCell(decimal.Parse(grandTotalCost.ToString()).ToString("N")));

        outerTableSecondColumn.AddCell(outerTableSecondColumnContent);

        #endregion

        // Add the columns to the table.
        outerTable.AddCell(outerTableFirstColumn);
        outerTable.AddCell(outerTableSecondColumn);

        // Add the table to the document.
        document.Add(outerTable);
        #endregion
        
        // Close the document.
        document.Close();
        
    }

    public PdfPCell GeneratePaymentDetailCell(String content) 
    { 
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell()
        {
            Phrase = new Phrase(content, FontFactory.GetFont("Consolas", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)),
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP,
            Border = Rectangle.BOX
        };

        return cell;
    }

    public PdfPCell GenerateGrandTotalCostCell(String grandTotalCost)
    {            
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell()
        {
            Phrase = new Phrase(grandTotalCost, FontFactory.GetFont("Consolas", 8, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK)),
            HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
            VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_TOP,
            Border = 1,
            BorderWidthTop = 1,
            BorderWidthBottom = 2
        };

        return cell;
    }

    enum DiscountType
    {
        FlatDiscount = 100,
        PercentDiscount = 200,
        NoDiscount = 300
    }

    enum TaxType
    {
        FlatTax = 100,
        PercentTax = 200,
        NoTax = 300
    }
```

Comment: Without any code there really isn't anything that we can do to help you. Explanations are great, but they usually map to what we _want_ code to do instead of what it _really does_.

Comment: Edit in place. Provided codes for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from my replication. By adding a blank row (in a form of AddCells()) in the **outerTableSecondColumnContent**, the cell shrinks down to fit the contents.